# Java - Space complexity with array in for loop

Tags: java, space-complexity

I know the time complexity is O(n). But **what is the space complexity of this code?** Meaning in worst case, what is the maximum amount of space needed? My guess is that it is O(1), since the array already has a constant amount of space, hence the space isn't being incremented.

**Code:**

```
public int[] countBits(int num) {
        int[] res = new int[num+1];

        for (int i = 0; i<num+1; i++){
            res[i] = Integer.bitCount(i);
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: So how does the amount of space change when I double the value of `num`?

Comment: As joe hints: the method "countBits" creates an array of length "num" (or "n") and so the space complexity is at least O(n).
Seeing as the rest of the method seems pretty harmless, I would say it's O(n).

Comment: @RoyShahaf But it's arguable that since the method's purpose is to return an array of size `n`, then any caller who calls it is knowingly creating an array of size `n`, and thus the size of the array should be "assigned" to the caller's space complexity and not to the method's.  By this argument, the "space complexity of _this method_" would be O(1).  I suspect that's what the OP is arguing.  This question really isn't possible to answer without more specific definitions, though.

Comment: `return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, num).map(Integer::bitCount).toArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Space Complexity** of an algorithm is *total* space of the input size including both Auxiliary space and space used by input.

Furthermore, Auxiliary Space is the temporary space used by an algorithm.

In your example, the input (*passed parameter `num`*) is included when calculating how much storage is required to create the array `new int[num+1]`. Likewise, the `for-loop` will be bigger.

As a conclusion, The Space complexity is **O(n)** as well as the Time Complexity is **O(n)**.

Comment: Is the array created by the algorithm "temporary" space, given that it is deliberately returned to the caller and not discarded when it exits?

Comment: @ajb I did not get your point, would ya please elaborate more.

Comment: I think of "temporary space" used by an algorithm as space that the algorithm allocates to hold intermediate data that it uses in computation.  The intermediate data is used to help compute the result, but is then not needed after the result is computed and can be deallocated/garbage collected.  Here, the space allocated _is_ the result, not intermediate data.  From the point of view of this algorithm, the space isn't temporary because it needs to stay around after the algorithm terminates.

Comment: @ajb I see what you mean now, I totally agree with that, but the misunderstanding happened because of my saying "*used by this algorithm*" . I meant by this phrase the algorithm that mentioned here "*Space Complexity of an algorithm...*" at the beginning of my answer. I'll change it to "*an algorithm*" instead. All in all it was a definition but I did not mean the algorithm/function in the OP's question.